# Mock CustomResouce with Fabric8

Tags: fabric8

I have applied Fabric8 to access CustomResource in the OpenShift, the following is an example code that works.

Now I am writing Junit test, I get stuck by mocking, there are a few of things that needs to mock

- How to mock a KubernetesClient?
- How to mock a MixedOperation ? Here it is certClient.
- How to mock a CustomResouce? Here we are accessing CertificateRequest that is a CRD.

Could anybody give some example code or point out how to achieve it? I appreciate it in advanced.

```
    try (KubernetesClient k8sClient = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {

      MixedOperation<
              CertificateRequest,
              KubernetesResourceList<CertificateRequest>,
              Resource<CertificateRequest>>
          certClient = k8sClient.resources(CertificateRequest.class);

      CertificateRequest certificateRequest =
          certClient.inNamespace(certNamespce).withName(certRequestName).get();
      if (certificateRequest == null) {
        logger.info(
            "CertificateRequest {} in certNamespce {} is a new one.",
            certRequestName,
            certNamespce);
      } else {
        certClient.inNamespace(certNamespce).withName(certRequestName).delete();
        logger.info(
            "Delete existing CertificateRequest {} in certNamespce {}, then create a new one.",
            certRequestName,
            certNamespce);
      }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      logger.error("Hit an error when create a CertificateRequest: ", exception);
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked out kubernetes mock server? I had written a blogpost about it: https://itnext.io/mock-kubernetes-api-server-in-java-using-fabric8-kubernetes-mock-server-81a75cf6c47c . Could you please check if this helps your use case?

Comment: Looks great, I will look into it. Thanks Rohan.

Answer (score 0):

Given your current logic encapsulated in a method like:

```
public void delete(String certNamespace, String certRequestName) {
  // Your logic
}
```

And a `CertificateRequest` class defined like:

```
  @Group("our-certificates.custom.example.com")
  @Version("v1")
  @Plural("certificaterequests")
  public static final class CertificateRequest
    extends CustomResource<CertificateRequestSpec, CertificateRequestStatus> {
  }
```

You can use the KubernetesMock server to perform 2 unit tests:

The first one verifies that only the GET request is performed to check if the resource exists:

```
  @Test
  void testDeleteWhenNotExistsShouldDoNothing() throws Exception {
    new CertificateRequestExample(kubernetesClient).delete("my-namespace", "my-cert");
    assertThat(mockServer.getLastRequest())
      .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("path", "/apis/our-certificates.custom.example.com/v1/certificaterequests/my-cert")
      .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("method", "GET");
  }
```

The second one verifies that the DELETE request is performed. For this purpose, we first set an expectation to return 200 when checking for the resource existence.

```
  @Test
  void testDeleteWhenExistsShouldDelete() throws Exception {
    mockServer.expect().get().withPath("/apis/our-certificates.custom.example.com/v1/certificaterequests/my-cert")
      .andReturn(200, "{}").once();
    new CertificateRequestExample(kubernetesClient).delete("my-namespace", "my-cert");
    assertThat(mockServer.getLastRequest())
      .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("path", "/apis/our-certificates.custom.example.com/v1/certificaterequests/my-cert")
      .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("method", "DELETE");
  }
```

This is just one of the ways you can use the MockServer to provide coverage for that behavior.

In addition I would recommend maybe refactoring a little bit your logic to be able to test better. Right now you only rely on the logs to provide feedback about the results of the actions of the method. In the tests we assert the last request which is fine because I know the how the method was implemented (whiteboxed), so I'm sure what the last request is in both cases.

You can check the complete source code for this example at [GitHub](https://github.com/marcnuri-demo/kubernetes-client/blob/022eed4aca25343b304d6c093f2ac1e3161e56e1/crd/src/test/java/com/marcnuri/demo/kubernetesclient/CertificateRequestTest.java).